# Coldfusion: using Apache POI event API

Tags: excel, apache, coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I need to parse big Excel spreadsheet (approximately 20 sheets) sheet by sheet with ColdFusion. [cfspreadsheet](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html) tag fails when processing large amount of data with *[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded]*. Apache POI User API directly behaves the same way:

```
<cfscript>
  pkg = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage").open(JavaCast("string", fileName));
  // error on next line
  wb = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook").Init(pkg);
</cfscript>
```

I tried to use Apache POI [event API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) instead of User API but faced problems with java inheritance. Has anyone ever used `XSSF and SAX (Event API)` for big spreadsheets processing in ColdFusion?

Comment: have you followed this page: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ff9.html

Comment: Currently our apps are running under CF9 environment, but I'll take enhanced Java integration in CF 10-11 into consideration since we are planning to migrate to CF11. Now I'm playing with CFX API to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: @SergeyBabrenok - That feature is basically a rip of Mark Mandel's [JavaLoader.cfc](http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=javaloader.index), so you can do the same thing in CF9 or earlier. I have only used the event API from java. You could probably do it with a dynamic proxy as barnyr suggests, but from a coding and performance perspective, I suspect you are better off implementing it in java.

Comment: I suppose the other question is, can you up the Heap allocated to ColdFusion's JVM? Doing that may well be cheaper than almost any developer effort. Even if you cann't do that in production, I'd do it in development, just to exclude any infinite loops or other problems

Comment: @barnyr, yes, increasing heap size solves the problem, but I'm looking for more memory efficient solution. Thanks, Leigh, I'll review the approach with JavaLoader.cfc

Comment: *can you up the Heap..* That is a good point. If you have not already, that is definitely something you should investigate before expending the effort to roll-your-own. Ultimately the event api is better with larger spreadsheets than cfspreadsheet, but it also requires effort and lower level coding. Whether you really need to go that route all depends on your processing needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all I succeeded in using CF + [Apache POI Event API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) + [Mark Mandel's `JavaLoader.cfc`](http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=javaloader.index), Thank you @Leigh, @barnyr for all your help. I implemented excel parser in java using `XSSF and SAX Event API`, now it works and works very fast. This wasn't easy due template to parse wasn't simple and as were denoted in comments increasing heap size may be cheaper.

Comment: Do not know if you still have the code, but it would be helpful to others if you posted a few snippets and/or a brief outline of your approach.